# Php display all non-duplicate images

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing

I have a database containing images for product. I'm displaying images from the database by this.

```
$sql="select imagename from table where item_id='$id'";
```

Then i select all the names and select all the images from the images folder. But there are some duplicate images in the folder. I cant remove them manually as there are thousands of images. I have a script that compares two images and tells whether they are same or not. But how do i compare all images and select only the ones that are not identical
Example: The compare script works like this!

```
$a-image1.jpg;
$b=image2.jpg;
$sameimage=$samecheck->compare($a,$b);
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicate images?

Comment: Actually they were all downloaded from an xml file on a different server! For some reason it copied the same links multiple times

Comment: Why didn't you just use Filezilla or something to copy the files straight to file manager?

Comment: Ummm actually it's kinda hard to explain how the duplicates were made! The main thing is I need a solution for this! Hope you understand!

Comment: Well, I would tell you to just delete the images, fix the links, and re-download them...

Comment: Nope cant delete and download all as there are thousands of images like I said!

Comment: Wouldn't that only take a few hours if you have a semi-fast connection?

Comment: Minimum number of images per product= 15
No of products =3035 !

Comment: You have 15 duplicate images per product? o.O

Comment: No no, total no of images per product= at least 15. Duplicate images may be 2-3 per product

Answer (score 0):

you could retrieve all the images which are duplicates by

```
$sql="select imagename from table GROUP BY imagename HAVING COUNT(imagename) > 1";
```

may be not 100% correct but is a good starting point.